# Select an object based on the condition in nested array(LINQ ,MongoDB)

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb, model-view-controller, asp.net-core

```
{
"Id": 1234,
"CommentType": "project",
"EntityReferenceId": "1345-154-154",
"Members": [{
    "MemberId": "1354",
    "Name": "a",
    "Email": "cdc@df.com"
}],
"Threads": [{
        "Id": "233",
        "UserReferenceId": "32343",
        "UserName": "433434",
        "CommentByUserType": "Agent",
        "Content": "dfdfdsfs sfdf sdf",
        "PostedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "Active": true,
        "Attachment": [{
            "AttachmentName": "ad",
            "AttachmentUrl": "http://fdf.jpg"
        }]
    },
    {
        "Id": "233",
        "UserReferenceId": "32343",
        "UserName": "433434",
        "CommentByUserType": "Agent",
        "Content": "dfdfdsfs sfdf sdf",
        "PostedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "Active": false,
        "Attachment": [{
            "AttachmentName": "ad",
            "AttachmentUrl": "http://fdf.jpg"
        }]
    }]
}
```

I am using MongoDb to linq,
This is my Comment" object format.for each Project there is a comment object.Each Comment object contains a list of "Threads"(you can see this above example).I want to load the "Comment" object with all thread which is Active("Active": true)

```
var result = _context.Comments
                     .AsQueryable()
                     .Where(x => x.EntityReferenceId == EntityReferenceId &&
                                 x.CommentType == Type && 
                                 x.Threads.Any(z=>z.Active==true))
                     .FirstOrDefault();
```

I used this query but it loading all threads if Any thread have "Active" value is true.

```
 x.Threads.Any(z=>z.Active==true)
```

returns only bool values.I need a solution please

Comment: Have you tried to replace `Any` with `Where` and see the result?

Comment: I think we cant use "Where".Operator && cannot be applied to operands of type bool and IEnumerable<Threads>

Comment: That condition will not work cause you getting a master object based on child condition and master object contain multiple child you are not filtering child.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `x.Threads.Any(z=>z.Active==true)` be `where` condition. 
or you will judge `Threads` collection is contain `Active==true` data.

A simple way you can do like this.

```
var result = _context.Comments
         .AsQueryable()
         .Where(x => x.EntityReferenceId == EntityReferenceId &&
                     x.CommentType == Type)
         .FirstOrDefault();

if (result!=null)
{
    result1.Threads = result1.Threads.Where(z => z.Active == true);
}
```

Or

use `select` method

```
var result = _context.Comments
                     .AsQueryable()
                     .Where(x => x.EntityReferenceId == EntityReferenceId &&
                                 x.CommentType == Type)
                     .Select(o => new Comment{
                        Id = o.Id,
                        Members = o.Members,
                        EntityReferenceId = o.EntityReferenceId,
                        CommentType = o.CommentType,
                        Threads = o.Threads.Where(z => z.Active == true)
                     })
                     .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I think this is not a proper way,why because,in the first query it will take the whole threads even if it is not active.if there is big amount of inactive comments it will also load.by cause of this it will be slow.

Comment: But this Downcasting is not supported ,I am using mongoDb database